# Is it possible to import app's js file inside cordova-plugin source code?

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a custom cordova-plugin that needs to depend on project's `js` file. Is it possible to import it in the plugin source code or I have to inject the dependency on startup to the plugin itself?